# BeautifulSoup not letting me get the text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to get all the text in  tag

It gives me the text in the console, but it doesn't put it in the `.txt` file.

It works with `body.text`, but not with `article.text`. I don't know what to do.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
#import re

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.bodoniparavia.it/index.php/it/amministrazione-trasparente/bandi-di-gara-e-contratti.html')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')


body = soup.body
article = body.find('article')
article1 = article.text
print(article1)

x = open('file.txt','w')
x.write(article1)
x.close
```

Comment: The html on that page might be malformed. The lxml parser is quite strict, and will simply ignore parts of the document if the html is invalid. Have you tried using a different parser? https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers

Comment: It prints it to me, tho. I get all the text and everything is fine, but it doesn't get into the txt file

Comment: Don't know. `x.close` should be `x.close()`. But it ought to work even if you didn't close the file. What type is `article.text`? Maybe try `x.write(article.get_text())` ?

Comment: It works for me. No adjustments needed. (Not even an error because of that `x.close` but that may be coincidence.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working fine for me but try adding `encoding = 'utf-8'` to the write statement. So the code would now look like this

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
#import re

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.bodoniparavia.it/index.php/it/amministrazione-trasparente/bandi-di-gara-e-contratti.html')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')


body = soup.body
article = body.find('article')
article1 = article.text
print(article1)

x = open('file.txt','w',encoding = 'utf-8')
x.write(article1)
x.close()
```

Comment: Adding the encoding does not do anything else for me, although I do admit it might be my system is set to use UTF8 by default. Or, since that page metadata *says* it is `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`, possibly the text is passed on unchanged.